# Retornar último campo incluído jQuery

Tags: jquery

Possuo um campo valor com a classe chamada `.amount-debit`, faço a soma automática de tudo que pertencer a essa classe. 
Como os campos são incluidos dinamicamente, de que forma que eu poderia buscar somente o valor da última linha adicionada?

HTML

```
<div id="debit-after">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Amount</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money disabled-inputs amount-debit" id="debit[0][amount]" name="debit[0][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="25,000.00">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" id='debit-transaction-edit'>
            <a href="#" class="remove_field_debit_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="debit-transaction-edit"><i class="fa fa-plus icon-add"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money disabled-inputs amount-debit" id="debit[1][amount]" name="debit[1][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="50,000.00">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" id='debit-transaction-edit'>
            <a href="#" class="remove_field_debit_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="debit_total_rows" name="debit_total_rows" value="2">
</div>
```

jQuery da soma e inclusão

```
function countamountdebit(){
   var total = 0;
   $(".amount-debit").each(function(){
      total += +(this.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
   });
   $("#amount_total_debit").text(total.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
   set_avaliable_balance();
   set_balance_total();
}

countamountdebit();
$(document).on("keyup", ".amount-debit", countamountdebit);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.money').maskMoney();
    var max_fields      = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $("#debit-after"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".debit-transaction-edit"); //Add button ID
    var total_debit     = $("#debit_total_rows").val();

    var x = total_debit; //initlal text box count    
    add_button.click(function(e){ //on add input button click        
        e.preventDefault();
        $(wrapper).append('<hr/><div class="note"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input money amount-debit" placeholder="Amount" value="" id="debit['+ x +'][amount]" name="debit['+ x +'][amount]"></div></div><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="date" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Date" id="debit['+ x +'][ddate]" name="debit['+ x +'][ddate]"></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="debit['+ x +'][details]" name="debit['+ x +'][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction"></div></div><div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="remove_field_debit_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a></div></div></div><div><hr/>'); //add input box
        $('.money').maskMoney();
        $(document).on("keyup", ".amount-debit", countamountdebit);
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field_debit_edit", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); x--;
        countamountdebit();
    })
});
```

Preciso montar um jQuery onde busca o último campo adicionado, com seu respectivo valor. 
E incluir numa div chamada "last_deposit"

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: No HTML que você passou, em qual das DIV's / campo especificamente fica o " valor " que você quer pegar ? No caso, a DIV / campo que é duplicada(o).

Comment: Nesse aqui @leo

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money disabled-inputs amount-debit" id="debit[0][amount]" name="debit[0][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="25,000.00">

Comment: Por ser dinâmico, o retorno dele deveria ser sempre o último valor do campo debit[x][amount]

Comment: Certo, cara existe um função do jQuery que se chama ```last()```, onde tu procura pelo ultimo filho criado de algum elemento em especifico, ou classe, id e afins. Pode ser uma solução para você

Comment: Vou adicionar uma resposta mais ou menos com uma lógica disso pra você ter como exemplo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99752/discussion-between-sr-andre-baill-and-leo).

Answer (score 2):

Cara, conforme falei eu fiz um exemplo para você ter de base. A questão que você pode fazer para resolver é usar o atributo `last()` do jQuery que sempre vai pegar o ultimo atributo existente, seja de uma classe, id ou elemento especifico que você setar. Com isso, é só pegar o seu `val()` e popular em outro input. Como você já tem uma função dinâmica, sempre que você adicionar ou excluir algum input, o valor será alterado para o ultimo existente. A unica coisa que você precisa fazer é adicionar uma nova `class`a esse input que é repetido para ele identificar sempre o ultimo. O código de teste foi esse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="open-iconic-master/font/css/open-iconic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <input type="text" class="pega-valor" placeholder="Amount" value="25,000.00">
            <input type="text" class="pega-valor" placeholder="Amount" value="30,000.00">
            <input type="text" class="pega-valor" placeholder="Amount" value="35,000.00">
            <input type="text" class="pega-valor" placeholder="Amount" value="40,000.00">
            <input type="text" class="pega-valor" placeholder="Amount" value="45,000.00">
            <input type="text" class="pega-valor" placeholder="Amount" value="50,000.00">
            <input type="text" class="pega-valor" placeholder="Amount" value="55,000.00">

            <input type="text" id="retornaValor" value="">
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var ultimo = $(".pega-valor").last().val();
        $("#retornaValor").val(ultimo);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

E o resultado sairá assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ok, o problema é que se eu remover o último registro, ele assumirá o registro anterior?

Comment: Se você implementar ele em sua função dinâmica, sim.